# mount an .iso converted from .bin

Tags: mount, iso

please how do I mount an .iso converted from .bin?
the .bin had no .cue si I created one the lines of the .cue file:

```
FILE "file.bin" BINARY
TRACK 01 MODE1/2352
INDEX 01 00:00:00
```

I used command `bchunk Setup-1a.bin Setup-1a.cue Setup-1a`
when trying to mount my .iso file using `mount Setup-1a01.iso /mnt/iso`

```
mount: you must specify the filesystem type
```

than I tried `mount -t iso9660 Setup-1a01.iso /mnt/iso/` but

```
mount: wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock on /dev/loop0,
       missing codepage or helper program, or other error
       In some cases useful info is found in syslog - try
       dmesg | tail  or so
```

Thank you for your help

Comment: Maybe it's a `udf` filesystem?

Answer (score -1):

try this:

```
mount -o loop Setup-1a01.iso /mnt/iso
```

Comment: well didn't work

Comment: `mount -o loop -t iso9660 img.iso /mnt/image`